# How to configure a project connection manager in SSIS 2012 by environment variable

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis, ssis-2012

is it possible to configure a project connection manager (by expression) DB URL by Environment Variable?

I saw that I can use the Visual Studio Configuration Manager to change project parameters but I found no way to change the DB URL of a project connection manager.

The reason is, that another SSIS developer is using a different DB URL to his local SQL Server instance.

Thanks

Comment: Are you attempting to set the value in Visual Studio/SSDT or are you talking about the actual configuration in the SSISDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that there is no way to use expressions in a project connection manager. What I did now is using an Alias.

So I defined an alias DWH which points to my local server localhost. The other developer is using the same alias name but points to his local named instance.